# How to refresh the timestamp information of a specific Cache?

Tags: acumatica

I went in to a situation where i need to reload the information from the database to a specific cache to do some re-calculation.

I tried the following. After this i am able to read the new information from the DB, but still the save is giving me PXLockViolationException.

```
 this.<VIEW>.Cache.Clear();
 this.<VIEW>.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
 this.<VIEW>.Select();
```

Please assist.

I used the

> this.Base.SelectTimeStamp();

But will this reload all timestamps? i just need my cache information to be updated. anyone knows about it?

Comment: Your first code snippet should work to clear cache values and get the ones from DB even though I would not recommend this beside as a last resort. Same recommendation about manually editing timetamps. What are you trying to do with that ? What kind of calculation do you need done ?

Comment: My case is, I have a master table and a running number, the running number might be added/subtracted from multiple docs. So Doc A updates value = 0+50. Next doc which going to save may update the same value, here it should take 50 then add/subtract the value. If i am unable to refresh this info from DB, users get the errors very frequently and they are forced to reload the info which results to lost of work.

Answer (score 0):

For the case which you described, when you have multiple people opening the same document, consider usage of [PXAccumulator](https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=4addf6d6-3ae5-0141-2edf-e44ff68a4a2b). One of it's purposes is to apply deltas to some property of DAC class without invalidating updated record. [Here](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2019/02/concurrent-update.html) Sergey describes a bit more about internals, also feel free to read documentation on implementing of it.